# Question regarding the definition of the action of $sl_2$ on a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, lie-algebras

Let $L$ be a simple  $sl_2$-module of finite dimension over a field $K$ of characteristic $0$. 
Say $e,f,h$ is a basis of $sl_2$. In the notes I am reading it only defines the action of $e,f,h$ on the basis elements of $L$. 
From this I see that we get the action of $e,f,h$ on all elements of $L$.

I was wondering: Is the action of other elements of $sl_2$ determined by linearity? i.e. for example,  given any $a, b \in K$ and $x \in L$, we define 
$$
(a e) \cdot  (b x) := ab (e \cdot x)?
$$

I was getting confused because it doesn't  say anything about this. Thank you very much.

Comment: If $L$ is $sl_2$ module, then it is saying there is ring morphism $U(sl_2)\to End_K(L)$. Then the action is extending by linearity as $e,f,h$ spans $sl_2$ over $K$ via this ring homomorphism.

Comment: What is $U(sl_2)$?

Comment: If you have defined the module, then this is giving $sl_2\to End_K(L)$ morphism and this extends to tensor algebra but you also have $[x,y]-xy+yx$ inside the kernel of extended tensor algebra $T(sl_2)\to End_K(L)$. $U(sl_2)=T(sl_2)/([x,y]-xy+yx,...)$ where the quotient runs through all elements $x,y\in sl_2$.

Comment: "I was getting confused because it doesn't  say anything about this." On the contrary, it says that $span\{e,f ,h\}$ is a vector space, and the module $L=V$ is also a vector space.

Comment: @user45765  When you say the $sl_2→End_K(L)$ morphism, this is a morphism of algebras? Also I guess the short answer to my original question is yes..?

Comment: $sl_2\to End_K(L)$ is just $K-$morphism s.t. its image respects commutator relations in $End_K(L)$ which is the reason why it extends to $K-$algebra(tensor algebra) level morphism.